# Programmatically switch NLog targets to/from async

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, nlog

I have been trying to programmatically flip the NLog async switch on and off for a long time.  I am getting nowhere.  I have code that appears to do what I want, but after making the changes, I get no logging at all.  Here's what I've found so far:

When the NLog config file contains `async=true`, then at runtime, I will have two targets (`LogManager.Configuration.AllTargets`) for each target in the config file.  One is the original target, renamed with "_wrapped" at the end.  The other is the original (now renamed) target wrapped in an `AsyncTargetWrapper`, and given the name of my original target.

Before doing anything (to turn on or off async), I first clear all of the `LoggingRules`.

To turn off async, I get the wrapped target from the `AsyncTargetWrapper`, rename it to the original name, remove the wrapper target (which seems to remove the original too), then re-add the original target (which has now been given its original name again).  Then I create a `LoggingRule` and set the appropriate logging levels. Finally, I call `LogManager.ReconfigExistingLoggers()`.  At this point, something is broken, as I will get no logging whatsoever.

I follow a similar process when turning async on, except this time, I rename the original target, create an `AsyncTargetWrapper` for it, then add the new wrapper target. Again, I create a `LoggingRule` for the new target and set the logging levels. At this point, something is broken, as I will get no logging whatsoever.

The code is below:

```
LogManager.Configuration.LoggingRules.Clear();

if (async) // turning async ON
{
    foreach (var target in LogManager.Configuration.AllTargets)
    {
        if (!(target is AsyncTargetWrapper))
        {
            string targetName = target.Name;
            // rename the synchronous target to indicate that it is going to be wrapped by another target (an asynchronous wrapper)
            target.Name = $"{target.Name}_wrapped";

            // create an asynchronous target wrpper and give it the name of the synchronous target's original (non-wrapped) name
            AsyncTargetWrapper asyncTarget = new AsyncTargetWrapper(target) { Name = targetName };

            LogManager.Configuration.AddTarget(asyncTarget);

            LoggingRule asyncRule = new LoggingRule("*", asyncTarget);
            if (_minLevel != null && _maxLevel != null)
            {
                asyncRule.EnableLoggingForLevels(_minLevel, _maxLevel);
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (var level in LogLevel.AllLevels.Except(new List<LogLevel>() { LogLevel.Off }))
                {
                    if (Logger.IsEnabled(level)) asyncRule.EnableLoggingForLevel(level);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
else // turning async OFF
{
    foreach (var target in LogManager.Configuration.AllTargets)
    {
        if (target is AsyncTargetWrapper)
        {
            // get the wrapped (synchronous) target from the wrapper
            Target syncTarget = ((AsyncTargetWrapper)target).WrappedTarget;

            // rename the synchronous target (remove "_wrapped" from the end of its name)
            syncTarget.Name = target.Name.Replace("_wrapped", "");

            // remove the wrapper target
            LogManager.Configuration.RemoveTarget(target.Name);

            LogManager.Configuration.AddTarget(syncTarget);

            // create a rule for the wrapped (synchronous) target
            LoggingRule syncRule = new LoggingRule("*", syncTarget);

            // set the logging level for the synchronous target
            if (_minLevel != null && _maxLevel != null)
            {
                syncRule.EnableLoggingForLevels(_minLevel, _maxLevel);
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (var level in LogLevel.AllLevels.Except(new List<LogLevel>() { LogLevel.Off }))
                {
                    if (Logger.IsEnabled(level)) syncRule.EnableLoggingForLevel(level);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

LogManager.Configuration.Reload();
LogManager.ReconfigExistingLoggers();
```

I don't think those last two lines are needed, but I tried them because nothing else was working.

There must be a correct way to flip the async flag, but I don't know what it is.  Can anyone tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem.  I had a working implementation in the past, so this was all very confusing for me.  There were problems with my old implementation, so I decided to refactor it, but made a mistake in the new implementation.  I left out a **critical** line of code!  New logging rules must be added to the configuration after they are created:

```
LogManager.Configuration.LoggingRules.Add(syncRule);
```

Now it works exactly as I want it to.  Whew!